# Image fails to display

Tags: android

I want to display an image using a file path .

```
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140524_150944.jpg
```

Here is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_single_new"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code i am using.

```
package com.bridge.bridgeinventory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SingleImage extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_image);
     ImageView image = (ImageView)
            findViewById(R.id.item_single_new);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setMaxHeight(100);
    image.setMaxWidth(100);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    Intent  i=getIntent();
     String myimage =i.getStringExtra("photo").trim();  
    Log.e("image path", myimage);
     Bitmap m= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myimage);
     if(m==null)
     {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image was deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     image.setImageBitmap(m);

}


}
```

The intent extral prints out correctly(as shown above) but the image does not display.

I only see a black patch instead of the image.

Is there anything simple i am missing?

This was supposed to be something simple but it has completely defeated me!

Ronald

This is how i get the path to store in the db.

```
public void GetPhoto(View v)
{
    Intent picintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    picintent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(picintent,GET_PHOTO);    

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
        if(requestCode==GET_PHOTO){
        if (resultData != null) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToLast();

                String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                cursor.close();             
                bridgephoto=imagePath;
                Log.e("imagepath", bridgephoto);
        }
        }
            }
```

The bridgephoto variable is a class level variable
After getting from the intent, i use it to set the photo proprty like below.

```
bridge.setBridgePhoto(bridgephoto);
```

Then i have a listview that displays the bridges . It has an a context menu with an option to display the bridge photo.

Here is the code for the photo menu item

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
     String menuItemName =menuitems[menuItemIndex];
     final AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo(); 
     final int pos = menuInfo.position;
if(menuItemName=="Photo")
{
    Bridge b= (Bridge)ba.getItem(pos);
    String image=b.getBridgePhoto();
    /// put it in an intent!
    Intent i= new Intent(Bridges.this,SingleImage.class);
    i.putExtra("photo",image);
    startActivity(i);


}
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

It is the string extral that is passed to the SingleImage activity.

But i have used Log.e to test the string(image path) and it appears correct.

Comment: How are your parsing the URL to your intent and where did you get that path from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had left that part out. Let me add it as an edit on the main question.